# WSO2 API Manager slow SQL query on Store rest API causing bad UI performance

Tags: mysql, sql, wso2-api-manager

The deployment is as follows:

- Mgr node: Default (Store+Pub), Gateway-Manager.
- Worker nodes: GW-Workers, Key-Managers

---

We use MySQL NDB as our API Manager database. Very slow API loading times observed on the Store UI. Using the Chrome Dev-Tools, I saw when an API is clicked to open (using a logged in session) will call the following API:

> http://{host/port}/store/apis/info?name={api-name}&version={v}&provider={provider}

Invoking the API manually(including the cookie) times out on our load-balancer (504).
Looking in the Store Jaggery files, I found the API it seems to call (../repository/deplyement/server/jaggeryapps/store/modules/api/api.jag), however I was unable to relate that to the actual API Impl. Using common sense I figured the API and related meta-data to it needed to be retrieved from the database.

Enabling slow query logs (25s) produced the following query, which gets logged when I tried to open an API:

```
SELECT
  ICA.CONSUMER_KEY AS CONSUMER_KEY,
  ICA.CONSUMER_SECRET AS CONSUMER_SECRET,
  IAT.ACCESS_TOKEN AS ACCESS_TOKEN,
  IAT.VALIDITY_PERIOD AS VALIDITY_PERIOD,
  ISAT.TOKEN_SCOPE AS TOKEN_SCOPE,
  AKM.KEY_TYPE AS TOKEN_TYPE,
  AKM.STATE AS STATE
FROM
  AM_APPLICATION_KEY_MAPPING AKM,
  IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN IAT,
  IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE ISAT,
  IDN_OAUTH_CONSUMER_APPS ICA
WHERE AKM.APPLICATION_ID = 149
  AND IAT.USER_TYPE = 'APPLICATION'
  AND ICA.CONSUMER_KEY = AKM.CONSUMER_KEY
  AND IAT.CONSUMER_KEY_ID = ICA.ID
  AND IAT.TOKEN_ID = ISAT.TOKEN_ID
  AND AKM.KEY_TYPE = 'PRODUCTION'
  AND (
    IAT.TOKEN_STATE = 'ACTIVE'
    OR IAT.TOKEN_STATE = 'EXPIRED'
    OR IAT.TOKEN_STATE = 'REVOKED'
  )
ORDER BY IAT.TIME_CREATED DESC;
```

This query takes an average of 80s to execute, returning about 33000 rows. The query is poorly written as there are no joins, and the following optimized version of it returns the same result set in < 3s:

```
SELECT
  `api_am_dev_1`.`ICA`.`CONSUMER_KEY` AS `CONSUMER_KEY`,
  `api_am_dev_1`.`ICA`.`CONSUMER_SECRET` AS `CONSUMER_SECRET`,
  `api_am_dev_1`.`IAT`.`ACCESS_TOKEN` AS `ACCESS_TOKEN`,
  `api_am_dev_1`.`IAT`.`VALIDITY_PERIOD` AS `VALIDITY_PERIOD`,
  `api_am_dev_1`.`ISAT`.`TOKEN_SCOPE` AS `TOKEN_SCOPE`,
  `api_am_dev_1`.`AKM`.`KEY_TYPE` AS `TOKEN_TYPE`,
  `api_am_dev_1`.`AKM`.`STATE` AS `STATE`
FROM
  `api_am_dev_1`.`AM_APPLICATION_KEY_MAPPING` `AKM`
  JOIN `api_am_dev_1`.`IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN` `IAT`
  JOIN `api_am_dev_1`.`IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE` `ISAT`
  JOIN `api_am_dev_1`.`IDN_OAUTH_CONSUMER_APPS` `ICA`
WHERE (
    (
      `api_am_dev_1`.`AKM`.`KEY_TYPE` = 'PRODUCTION'
    )
    AND (
      `api_am_dev_1`.`ISAT`.`TOKEN_ID` = `api_am_dev_1`.`IAT`.`TOKEN_ID`
    )
    AND (
      `api_am_dev_1`.`IAT`.`CONSUMER_KEY_ID` = `api_am_dev_1`.`ICA`.`ID`
    )
    AND (
      `api_am_dev_1`.`ICA`.`CONSUMER_KEY` = `api_am_dev_1`.`AKM`.`CONSUMER_KEY`
    )
    AND (
      `api_am_dev_1`.`IAT`.`USER_TYPE` = 'APPLICATION'
    )
    AND (
      `api_am_dev_1`.`AKM`.`APPLICATION_ID` = 149
    )
    AND (
      (
        `api_am_dev_1`.`IAT`.`TOKEN_STATE` = 'ACTIVE'
      )
      OR (
        `api_am_dev_1`.`IAT`.`TOKEN_STATE` = 'EXPIRED'
      )
      OR (
        `api_am_dev_1`.`IAT`.`TOKEN_STATE` = 'REVOKED'
      )
    )
  )
ORDER BY `api_am_dev_1`.`IAT`.`TIME_CREATED` DESC
```

Adding indexes does not seem to help the issue. We run a token clean-up every week so there are only about 20 000 tokens in the database in total ~ our QA is quite busy.

Question: is the query generated by Hibernate and is the only option to create a patch?

The WSO2 Store is an awesome developer portal but this is ruining the experience for many of our users.

Edit:

API Manager version = 2.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, the queries are not generated by hibernate or any other abstraction framework. All the queries are stored as String constants in the java class files, so yes, you would have to change the query and build a patch if you find the need to alter the underlying queries.

We ran into the same problem but adding the following index improved the store performance when clicking on an API to retrieve it's information significantly:
DB: apimgt 
Table: IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN
Columns: USER_TYPE, CONSUMER_KEY_ID, TOKEN_ID, TOKEN_STATE